# How to access different boot2docker instance in a virtual box

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, boot2docker

I created two boot2docker instances in virtual box:

"boot2docker-vm" {8674bb87-b7ba-4179-9a09-c779611b1d9a}

"boot2docker-work" {53ffd6d6-2fc4-4c4f-b34e-c2f8dd87dd40}

They use different boot2docker.iso and different profiles.

The first vm is default, so if you run 'docker images' outside the virtual machine, it will use the first one by default.

But how can I access the second boot2docker "boot2docker-work", I know 'boot2docker ssh' works, but I want to run docker command outside the virtual machine.

I tried to set DOCKER_HOST and ca, cert for the second vm, but has the following errors:
*An error occurred trying to connect: Get https://192.168.59.110:2376/v1.19/containers/json: dial tcp 192.168.59.110:2376: i/o timeout*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,I find a solution.

when we create a VM, it will connect to a vboxnet with IP, if the ip is 192.168.59.103, it will add 192.168.59 to routing table

192.168.58         link#10            UC              3        0 vboxnet

then if we start the vm, 192.168.58.103 will be added to the routing table with right gateway:

192.168.58.103     8:0:27:1e:d1:24    UHLWI           0     3120 vboxnet    210

But if we create another vm with ip 192.168.58.104, then it will not have a right gateway:

192.168.58.104         link#10            UC              3        0 vboxnet

This makes the vm not working.

So my solution is that, use 192.168.59, or 192.168.60, then all problems gone.

But can anyone explain the routing mechanism of this?